# Android studio dynamic fragments according to date

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have an android studio project with SQLite Room database. There is a table column that contains the date. I want to add several dynamic fragments according to the date and filter data month-wise, day-wise, year-wise, etc.

[image: Image of expected outcome]

How do I add tabs and fragments like this using `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create

> While your activity is running, you can make fragment transactions
> such as adding, removing, or replacing a fragment. In your
> FragmentActivity, you can get an instance of the FragmentManager,
> which can be used to create a FragmentTransaction. Then, you can
> instantiate your fragment within your activity's onCreate() method
> using FragmentTransaction.add(), passing in the ViewGroup ID of the
> container in your layout and the fragment class you want to add and
> then commit the transaction, as shown in the following example:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ExampleActivity() {
        super(R.layout.example_activity);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, ExampleFragment.class, null)
                .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need further help. Post your code and explain what isn't working. I'll be glad to help.